# How to make pagination from array object by use reactjs

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I have a data in this link i want to put just 10 indexes in each page and make pagination for the other data
to see this array visit http://demo9197058.mockable.io/users

.

.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';

...

<ReactPaginate
      previousLabel={'previous'}
      nextLabel={'next'}
      breakLabel={'...'}
      breakClassName={'break-me'}
      pageCount={this.state.pageCount}
      marginPagesDisplayed={2}
      pageRangeDisplayed={5}
      onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
      containerClassName={'pagination'}
      subContainerClassName={'pages pagination'}
      activeClassName={'active'}
/>
```

Comment: thank you , but how making pagecount for array object ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the page count you need to define your page size and divide the total amount of entries by that number.

For example, if your page size is 25, you get your page count by doing something like:

```
const PAGE_SIZE = 25;
const pageCount = data.length / PAGE_SIZE;

this.setState({ pageCount })
```

So your complete code would be something like

```
Import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate'

class Paginate extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = { pageCount: null;
    }

    const PAGE_SIZE = 25;
    const pageCount = data.length / PAGE_SIZE;

    this.setState({ pageCount })

    render() {
        return (
        // your code goes here

         <ReactPaginate
             previousLabel={'previous'}
             nextLabel={'next'}
             breakLabel={'...'}
             breakClassName={'break-me'}
             pageCount={this.state.pageCount}
             marginPagesDisplayed={2}
             pageRangeDisplayed={5}
             onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
             containerClassName={'pagination'}
             subContainerClassName={'pages pagination'}
             activeClassName={'active'}
        />
    )
}
```